# How to give custom matching parameters to compare code list pattern using R?

Tags: r, compare, pattern-matching, matching, grepl

I want to compare data frame column for match and mismatch. In here i have codes in column a and their values in column b. I want to get match if column a has 1 and column b has male (1=male and 2=female) row wise and similarly there should be mismatch if given code does not satisfy.

if 1=male or 2=female then match else mismatch

Below is my tried code which works fine for simple pattern matching or exact value matching but i want it to work with codelist

```
ABData <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,1,1,2),
                     b = c("Male","Female","Male","Male","Male")

match<- ABData %>% rowwise() %>% filter(grepl(a,b))

mismatch<- ABData %>% rowwise() %>% filter(!grepl(a,b))
```

expected output:

```
Match
a     expected    actual
1     Male        Male
2     Female      Female
1     Male        Male
1     Male        Male

Mismatch
a     expected    actual
2     Female      Male
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an index to subset :

```
inds <- with(ABData, a == 1 & b == 'Male' | a == 2 & b == 'Female')
match_df <- subset(ABData, inds)
mismatch_df <- subset(ABData, !inds)
```

We then add `actual` column.

```
match_df <- transform(match_df, actual = b)
mismatch_df <- transform(mismatch_df, actual = ifelse(b == 'Male','Female', 'Male'))
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my questing...i want little help from you i have updated the questing for expected output....can check and help me ?